# How to export and sync an Artifactory repository to the filesystem?

Tags: artifactory

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to have a network share where people can access (read-only) the artifacts from an Artifactory repository.

Why? We use Artifactory to also keep track of big binaries like installation kits, ISO images and so on and it takes a lot of time to download all of them (sometimes as zips), unpack and run them. If these would be exported to a NFS/SMB share people would be able to only mount them in order to use them.

How can we achieve this? Please keep in mind that we also want to automate this, so the files would be updated by Artifactory when needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Artifactory supports WebDAV out of the box.](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+WebDAV)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's not possible at this moment and there is a feature request for enabling it:

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8302

Feel free to vote and to comment on it, allowing jFrog to realise how important is this use case.

I guess they should be able to provide a script that does mirror/sync a repository to a NFS share but that would almost double the storage space needed.

Instead if they would use hardlinks or symlinks to create a browsable tree of the repository inside the storage directory, this would be solved and no sync will be needed.